# Unitary operators and representations of Von-Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I found the following assertion and I would like to know why does it hold:

Let $\pi$ be a representation of a von-Neumann algebra such that $\pi=\pi_1 \oplus \pi_2$ where $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are irreducible representation. and let {$x_1,x_2$} linearly independent.
Now by theorem 1 from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC528430/pdf/pnas00694-0019.pdf) I know there is a self adjoint operator $B$ such that $Bx_i=(-1)^ix_i \ \ (i=1,2)$ and by taking exponent of fitting operator we can find unitary operator $A$ such that $Ax_i=(-1)^ix_i \ \ (i=1,2)$.

My Question is if I can find now a unitary element $a$ of the algebra such that $\pi(a)x_i=(-1)^ix_i \ \ (i=1,2)$. In other words any such unitary operator can be written as $\pi(a)$ where $a$ is unitary element of the algebra.

---

Note that $A$ is also unitary operator in $\pi(M)$ (where $M$ is the algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then the answer is yes only in case $\sigma(A)\neq S_1$ (that is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}$).

Indeed in that case we can find a continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(A)\subsetneq S_1$  such that $f(A)$ is self-adjoint and $e^{if(A)}=A$ (try to figure out what is $f$ by yourself). Notice that $f(A)\in \pi(M)$ so if $f(A)=\pi(X)$ for $X\in M$ we have $f(A)=\pi(Y)$ where $Y=\frac{1}{2}(X+X^*)$ a self-adjoint element. So by taking the unitary element $a=e^{iY}$ we end up with $\pi(a) = \pi(e^{iY}) = e^{i\pi(Y)} = e^{if(A)} = A$ as wanted.//

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for your answer! secondly, is $f$ simply the "arg" function on $S^1$?

Comment: @nedgrekerzberg - yes, $f$ is the extension of $\arg$ over $S_1$.